# Is it safe to execute "sudo reboot" on a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I’ve been using Google Compute Engine for 2 months now, I have a bunch of stuff installed on it.

Just installed a new kernel, so a reboot is required. I'd like to know if `sudo reboot` is safe. Meaning a reboot will not wipe out everything installed on the instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There’s nothing different in running `sudo reboot` in a instance versus on your own server.
This action shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Good answer! Basically a reboot is a reboot is a reboot. No muss, no fuss.

Comment: how about ephemeral IPs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author was worried if the disk is persistent or not.
Yes you can shutdown/start/reboot the instance and your data will persist.

Comment: and i worry about ephemeral ips

Comment: ephemeral ips wont change with reboots. You can get a static ip, which  is free of charge, as long as the instance is running. (free tier accounts are limited to one or two static ips i believe)

Comment: doesn't seem 100% sure, what if the ephemeral ip is allocated to other users in the time span between stop and start (again). In this time span, the instance is not running

Comment: if the instance is closed, it will get another public ip on the start.